# Python (development environment): Install Python 3.5.2, pip, and virtualenv on Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, powershell, virtualenv

**I'm having a problem trying to get the PowerShell virtualenvwrapper installed.**

Bellow is the process I'm going through:

/******

Experienced Python/Django developers often choose to instead run their Python apps within independent Python virtual environments.

These allow developers to have multiple different Django environments on a single computer, allowing them to create new websites (using the latest version of Django)while still maintaining websites that rely on older versions.

The Django developer team itself recommends that you use Python virtual environments.

******/

**1.** Access PowerShell as admin

> cd C:\
>
> mkdir Django
>
> cd Django

**2.** Get Python 3.5.2 (32 bits is the one I suggest) - https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/

> Customize the location: C:\Python35-32
>
> (make sure is installed in your path)

Once you’ve installed Python,
open up a PowerShell window and

> python

This is what you will see:

```
 Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

------------------- (CTRL + Z to exit the Python prompt)

**3.** Get Pip

Save the following script as get-pip.py:

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
(if you can not find it, ask me for a copy)

> python get-pip.py

To check if everything is working, just type pip at the command line:

> pip

Then, if all goes ok,

> pip install --upgrade setuptools
>
> pip install ez_setup

**4.** Install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper-powershell

> pip install virtualenv

(all good)

> pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell

**(having a problem here)**

```
C:\Django>pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell

Collecting virtualenvwrapper-powershell

  Using cached virtualenvwrapper-powershell-12.7.8.zip

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

      File "C:\Users\USERHP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9qxnn_l2\virtualenvwrapper-powershell\setup.py", line 76
        TOKEN_READ = 0x00020000L | 0x0008
                               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
C:\Users\USERHP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9qxnn_l2\virtualenvwrapper-powershell\
```

What can I do here?

**Thank you for the support**

Comment: FYI, that Ctrl+C exits Python's REPL is due to a bug in Windows 8 and 10, in which `ReadFile` doesn't set the last error to `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED` the way it's supposed to. Python's shell is supposed to default to raising a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception for Ctrl+C. To exit normally, as intended, type Ctrl+Z and press enter, or to kill Python type Ctrl+Break. This is what will continue to work when you upgrade to Python 3.6, which switched to calling `ReadConsole`, which works correctly.

Comment: The Windows installer gives you the option to install pip, which you should then upgrade to the latest version via `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Python 3 has the [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module. Give that a try.

Comment: As I say in http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/, I have some doubts as to how well virtualenvwrapper is supported on Windows. It may be better to use plain virtualenv.

Comment: Please do not put things like `[solved]` in the title, instead accepting the answer that worked (by clicking on the outline of a tick box) lets others know what is the accepted solution and closes the question - in addition to awarding reputation points.

Comment: That's just for organization, I don't need to open the question to know if got solved or not. @BurhanKhalid

Comment: an it's already marked

Comment: You can know if a question has an accepted answer because it will have a green square in the answer column on the main page.

Comment: you are right, but I like more to do this way, for own organization. What is the problem associated to do it this way? @BurhanKhalid

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

virtualenvwrapper-powershell interacts nicely with Python 2.7.
(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-powershell/2.7.1)

So, I suggest to install that as the system python AND then install Python 3.5.2 outside of the path.

Following steps:

1. Install Python 2.7 **ON** the path
2. Install Python 3.5.2 **OFF** the path
3. > pip

> pip install --upgrade setuptools
>
> pip install ez_setup

5. > pip install virtualenv
6. > pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell